# Annotate the own dataset to convert into forge's format

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am using [talon's email_extractor](https://github.com/mailgun/talon) to extract signature from the mail. But it doesn't seems to work properly with my data. I wanted to train the talon's classifier to my dataset but I need to change the dataset to [forge's format](https://github.com/mailgun/forge). How do I change the my data to the following forge's format:

```
#sig#--
#sig#Mike Smith
#sig#555-243-0623
```

I have dataset from [zendesk's api](https://developer.zendesk.com/)

EDIT-1:

My dataset is in this format :

```
Hi there!\n\nOur new project description is as follows:\n\nABC
is a .. company committed to producing works both new 
and\nrediscovered . We b 
performances\nare exactly alike; with every ads, new 
thoughtsfeelings......
**\n\n \n\nBest, \n\XYZ\n\n     \n\XYZ, xxx 
xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx\n\nUnsubscribe (https://media.XYZ.org/hs/manage- 
preferences/unsubscribe-all? 
d=Vnk5T44_PyVnW1b1YkV4mCt9cW3Z_sBZ3zhsYkW3Fbt723zd- 
J2W3P3Q7w3ZsjYmW3_fWSh6pjXx2VmWcP5724cW0N6P6s3r25DrQW7ZSHL  
sFPu8fNOrW7ByvX2ISZHyRP5Kjm4vKXy60COlsUqmvd1t9W- 
) Manage preferences (https://media.xyz.org/hs/manage/unsubscribe? 
d=Vnk5T44_PyVnW1b1YkV4mCt9cW3Z- 
J2W3P3Q7w3ZsjYmW3_fWSh6pjXx2VmWcP5724cW0N6P6s3r25DrQW7ZSHL- 
=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=756&_hsenc=JegN- 
sFPu8fNOrW7ByvX2ISZHyRP5KjmW
)\n\n\n\n--\n\nTheABC Company\nxx-xxx-xxx | 
ABC@gmail.com | ABC.org
```

I want :

```
#sig#Best
#sig#....
#sig#The ABC Company
#sig#ABC@gmail.com | ABC.org
```

Comment: share some sample dataset...